# Ethernet not working after resuming from sleep

Tags: networking, hp, ethernet, suspend

After resuming from sleep , Ethernet doesn't work and requires me to reboot.

When I try to connect to Ethernet after resuming from sleep it tries to connect and after about a minute it disconnects.

My laptop is a HP Pavilion g7-2269wm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that a work around is to restart the Ethernet driver after resuming from sleep. Use these commands after resuming from sleep

To do it run `lspci -k` . The output of the command for me is below

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:10.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 14)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 184b
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Now find your Ethernet controller and its module (driver) name in the command output. For me it is `r8169` but yours will be different (unless you have a similar laptop).

Then run (replace `<name>` with the module name like `r8169`)

```
sudo rmmod <name>
sudo modprobe <name>
```

For me it was (but yours will be different)

```
sudo rmmod r8169
sudo modprobe r8169
```

This will restart the Ethernet kernel module (driver). Now Ethernet should be working.

I am currently working on a automated solution which runs on every resume

Comment: Well well. That was easy enough. Phew! Now to figure out the exact `systemd` service that gets launched every time a power suspend/hibernate _terminates_ so that I might add that sequence of commands automagically, instead of doing them over and over again...
It should be simple enough to figure it out, right? Right...

Answer (score 0):

> sudo service network-manager restart

This will restart the network service and everything will be resumed

Comment: While this is certainly the case, it has the disadvantage of being overkill. At home, I always have _both_ a wired and and wi-fi connection active. The theory is that, if one of them goes down, I might be able to keep most of my remote sessions active until I manage to fix whatever is wrong with the failed interface. `service network-manager restart`, however, will break _both_ interfaces at the same time, even if it's just for some seconds... enough to sever _all_ existing connections.